# How to install pix2pix-tensorflow in colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

So I tried this:

```
    !pip install -q pix2pix-tensorflow
```

and this:

```
      !pip install git+https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow.git
```

but  nothing is working.

This is the error I am getting :

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting git+https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow
Cloning https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow to /tmp/pip-req-build-r59bl6ax
Running command git clone -q https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow /tmp/pip-req-build-r59bl6ax
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project git+https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow.
```

Comment: Have you tried the [Getting Started](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow#getting-started) guide in the repo?

Comment: @ Nick ODell, I looked at it  again and I still do not see anything that says how to add it to colab but maybe I am  missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `pix2pix` using the code below :

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git

from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
```